# Prevent monster spawning next to player Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make monsters spawn next to player when there is no other places anymore in the grid. This means after 32 places is occupied of 36 places. I am using while loop to prevent monsters spawning on me and preventing them to spawn on each other.

What I have tried in this method is to check player's neighbors but still it keep spawning next to player.

```
// re-roll for reasons:
        // 1. can't be on top of player
        // 2. x and y is occupied
        while((randomX == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX && randomY == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileY) ||
            occupationArray[randomX, randomY] == true) {

            //TODO if monsterList < 32 then monsters shouldn't spawn next to player
            if (monsterList.Count < 32 &&
                ((randomX == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX && // x=0 y= 1 || -1
                Mathf.Abs(randomY - selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileY) == 1) ||
                (Mathf.Abs(randomX - selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX) == 1 && // x= 1 || -1 y=0
                randomY == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileY))) {

                    randomX = Random.Range(0,6);
                    randomY = Random.Range(0,6);
            } else {
                randomX = Random.Range(0,6);
                randomY = Random.Range(0,6);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `while(random)` is pretty bad in terms of performance. did you consider determining the position by specifying a random angle and minimum distance from the player, then finding the nearest grid location to that point ?

Comment: or just iterating over the tiles, then determining if it's OK to spawn a monster on that tile?

Comment: The monsters will spawn on top of tiles and i would like it to spawn it to other places before spawning close to player.

Comment: Then in the second idea i gave, it would be a matter of sorting the tiles based on where you would prefer the monsters to spawn before doing the iteration

Comment: the code in your example is a bit sparse btw, so there's no real way i can make a working example

Comment: did you try looking on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ by the way?

Comment: thanks for effort, I will look into that link

Comment: why not make a list of existing tiles, and when you spawn a monster , add this tile to the list marked how filled. And only need to check this list next time if the tile is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Your while-loop checks only for the location of the player or an occupation by a monster, but not the distance to the player.
So you enter the math-part only when your first random position is a hit.
If you want to stick to a random-loop you need to make the distance calculation part of the while loop:

```
while((randomX == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX && 
   randomY == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileY) ||
  occupationArray[randomX, randomY] == true ||
  (monsterList.Count < 32 && DistanceToPlayer(randomX, randomY) == 1)) {
                randomX = Random.Range(0,6);
                randomY = Random.Range(0,6);
      }
```